# sqlalchemy: ORM update of composite property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know that, in sqlalchemy, it is possible to generate bulk updates from the ORM with the syntax:

```
session.query(My_table).update({'my_value' : "foo"})
```

However, if I have a composite property, sqlalchemy does not let me do

```
session.query(My_table).update({'my_composite_property' : instance_of_class_that_property_is_mapped_to})
```

Is there a way to do this?  It's possible to iterate over instances of My_table and do

```
instance_of_my_table.my_composite_property = instance_of_class_that_property_is_mapped_to
```

But this does an update for each instance and I'd like to do a batch update.

Comment: Any luck with your code? Am using SQLAlchemy Core and I tried the code: `'stmt = tbl.update().where(tbl.c.compsite_col_1 == bindparam('b_id_1'), tbl.c.compsite_col_2 == 'b_id_2').\
          values(**{'column_to_update_1': bindparam('b_column_to_update_1'), \
            'column_to_update_1': bindparam('b_column_to_update_2')})` However, I get the error `TypeError: where() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`